# How can I make this areamap/checkbox work both ways with JQuery? (JsFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

My app filters venue results by area using a form. The form contains a checkbox for each area and multiple areas can be checked. The page then returns only the venues which are in the checked areas.

The page also has a .png map image of a town showing all the differant areas and each area is clickable and corresponds with an area checkbox in the filter form. The map.png is the background of an image-map containing a poly shape for each area.

This javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('area').click(function(){
      var name = $(this).data("areanum");
      var $checkbox = $('#' + name);
      $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
      $checkbox.button('refresh');
    });       
  });
```

Links the areas on the map to their corresponding checkboxes. So if a user selects the northern area on the map, the northern area checkbox gets checked. However, if the user selects the northern area checkbox the northern area on the map doesn't get checked.

So if the area on the map gets clicked it checks the checkbox but if the checkbox gets clicked the area on the map does nothing.

How can I make this interaction work both ways?

**edit - generated html for an area and its associated checkbox**

*The area on the map*

```
<div class="map_container">

  <img alt="" class="map" height="450" src="/assets/maps/mainmap.png" usemap="#mainmap" width="450" />

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area id="north" data-areanum="area-42" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >
  </map>              
</div>
```

*its associated checkbox*

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" id="filter_form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
        <p class="area_check"><input id="area-42" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="42" />
        <label for="area-42"><p1>North</p1></label></p>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="filter_form_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Show me"/></p2>
    </div>
</form></div>
```

**jsfiddle** *this is a mini version of what is happening in my app*

http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing, and help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Definition of [backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility).

Comment: What does this have to do with backwards-compatibility?

Comment: You should rename your question -- "backwards compatible" is not what you're looking for. That aside: what do you want your map to actually do when a checkbox is checked? Are you changing colors of tiles? Changing some element overlaying the map?

Comment: Apologies, been edited by DmitryB now

Comment: @KenRedler, Thanks for having a look, each area in the image-map changes colour when clicked (using the jQuery maphighlight plugin), so I would like them to act as though they had been clicked when each areas associated checkbox gets checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var $area = $('area');
    $area.click(function(){
        var $checkbox = $('#' + $(this).data("areanum"));
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked')).button('refresh');
    });
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        $area.filter('[name="' + this.id + '"]').trigger('click');
    }); 
});
```

This registers clicks on `checkbox` elements, finds the corresponding `area` element and triggers a click on that element (so basically this code simulates clicking on the image-map when clicking on the `checkbox` elements).

If you find yourself using the same selector more than once right next to each other, then you can chain the function calls to that selector to avoid the overhead of selecting DOM elements.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing your jsfiddle here is the solution I came up with:

```
$(function() {
    var $area = $('area');
    $area.click(function(){
        var $checkbox = $('#' + $(this).data("areanum"));
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked')).button('refresh');
    });

    //instead of binding to the input elements, this binds to their associated label elements
    $('label').click(function () {

        //trigger a click on the area element that is associated with this label element (the reference is in the `for` attribute)
        $area.filter('[data-areanum="' + $(this).attr('for') + '"]').trigger('click');

        //now stop this event handler from bubbling over to the input element (this is done because if we let the event get to the input element then it will un-hilight the label element)
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/1/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer, that looks like the exact thing I'm after. The area on the map still won't highlight however. I'll add the generated html for an area and its associated checkbox to my question. I'm pretty awful with javascript could the line $area.filter change to make it work?

Comment: I'll assume you're using the `MapHilight` plugin from this attribute: `data-maphilight`. If that's the case then I'm not sure how you would go about using my solution for that plugin. It uses a `<canvas>` element to create its "hilight" effects.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my question if it would be of any use.

Comment: @Dave I updated your JSFiddle with code that behaves like you want: http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/1/. It's always a good idea to post your code in a jsfiddle, it makes it so much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a checkbox click event handler that will do the reverse of what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean to keep them in sync? like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/s24yW/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah keep them both in sync so which ever gets selected its associated 'other half' gets selected too. I'll have a play about and see if I can get your solution to fit with what I have. (I'm bad with javascript).

Comment: if you add your html into the js fiddle , ill help with the javascript